# Select array with null values

Tags: sql

```
id  column1
1   ['A']
2   ['A', 'B', 'C']
3   [null]
```

I'd like to select row 3, but trying

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(column1, null)`

returns empty result. I'm lost as to why that's not selecting row 3. Help?

Comment: What _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)?  We need to know this in order to answer your question.

Comment: Accept the answer please to give credit to @naufalbasara :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you are working in a PostgreSQL environment. Simply can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE null = any(column1)
```

or if null equals to empty string, just change it correspondingly

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE '' = any(column1)
```

See the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) for more

Comment: the logic of comparing the element in the column to null works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

select * from table where column1 is null;
which means it will select all the rows with null value in column1
or for Post GRE SQL
select * from table where null = any(column1)

Comment: Surround code blocks by triple backticks.